# A simple Blackjack Game

Tags: java, printing

I am building a Blackjack game using Object Oriented Programming.

I wrote this so far:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Blackjack {
    public static String[] Card = new String[12];
    public static String[] Suits = {"D", "H", "S", "C"};


    public void setCard(String[] c) {
        Card = c;
        Card[0] = "A";
        Card[1] = "2";
        Card[2] = "3";
        Card[3] = "4";
        Card[4] = "5";
        Card[5] = "6";
        Card[6] = "7";
        Card[7] = "8";
        Card[8] = "9";
        Card[9] = "10";
        Card[10] = "J";
        Card[11] = "Q";
        Card[12] = "K";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Blackjack.");

        Random rand = new Random();

        int card_Sign1 = (int) (Math.random() * 13);
        int card_Sign2 = (int) (Math.random() * 13);

        int Suit1 = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
        int Suit2 = (int) (Math.random() * 4);

        System.out.print(Card[card_Sign1]);

    }
}
```

The output I get is `Welcome to Blackjack` then `null`. I was wondering if I could get a little help on how to solve this.

Comment: You need to call the setCard method. Without doing that every item in your array is null by default. Also, that method does not need to take a parameter since you don't actually use it and since it is an array of length 12 the highest index you can access is 11.

Comment: The particular answer has been given. But why you created an instance of `Random` and never used it?

Answer (score 2):

As csmckelvey said in a comment, you need to call the setCard method inside your main method. Otherwise, the card array never gets its initial values.

You have another problem as well--You declare your array with a size of 12:

```
public static String[] Card = new String [12];
```

But then you try to assign it 13 values in setCard. You'll need to change it to have a size of 13.

Also, setCard() doesn't need a paramater, you're fine just setting the values for Card.

Aside from that, looking good, keep it up!

Comment: Also, if you're going to call `setCard` directly from `main`, it will need to be declared `static`.

Comment: Good catch! `public static void setCard() {`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the call to `setCard()` and you don't need to pass parameters to `setCard()`. Try this:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

System.out.println("Welcome to Blackjack.");

Random rand = new Random();

int card_Sign1 = (int)(Math.random()*13);
int card_Sign2 = (int)(Math.random()*13);

int Suit1 = (int)(Math.random()*4);
int Suit2 = (int)(Math.random()*4);

setCard();

System.out.print(Card[card_Sign1]); 

} 

public void setCard() {
    Card[0] = "A";
    Card[1] = "2";
    Card[2] = "3";
    Card[3] = "4";
    Card[4] = "5";
    Card[5] = "6";
    Card[6] = "7";
    Card[7] = "8";
    Card[8] = "9";
    Card[9] = "10";
    Card[10] = "J";
    Card[11] = "Q";
    Card[12] = "K";
}
```